# Is there a way to force Google Drive API to compress files and let me download an archive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

People of Earth! Hello. As I can see in the docs, I'm able to download only one file using one API request. In order to download 10 files - I have to make 10 requests that makes me sad... Google Drive UI allows us to download archived files after selecting files and clicking on "download". Is there the same feature in the API that would allow me to download the desired number of files at once? I need Google Drive API to compress files and let me download an archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. I believe (haven't tested it) that Google will respect `Accept-Encoding: gzip` for content downloads.